# Why is my terminal producing a beep sound whenever I am printing characters for C++ code?

Tags: c++, ascii, beep

I am a beginner in Programming in C++. Recently in my C++ Book there was a quick exercise to print a set of characters from `a` to `z`. I typed the following code in Visual Studio 2019.

```
char alphabet = 0;
    
while (alphabet < 130)
{
    cout << char(alphabet + 1)<<"\n";
    ++alphabet;
}
```

I can understand why my code prints weird characters and signs, because I have chosen ASCII characters valued from 1 to 130. However, the real problem is that my terminal produces a beep sound every time, even after all the characters are printed. I know for a fact that a beep sound is part of the ASCII character set, but it is only the character 7. But in my case the terminal produces a beep sound continuously until I kill the executable from the task manager.
Please tell me the reason why there is a problem like this and please do not have a problem saying that this code is printing more than `a` to `z`. I just chose a random number so that I get the characters `a` to `z` in the terminal.
I am running this code on Windows 7, so if the OS has something to do with it please tell.

Comment: `for (char c = 'a'; c <= 'z'; ++c) cout << c << "\n";` will work for ASCII.  Not so good for EBCDIC.

Comment: There are 26 letters in the (English) alphabet; adding capital and lowercase gives 52. Printing 300 values is going to show far more than 52 characters. The remaining 248 include a great deal of stuff that looks like nonsense.

Comment: There is nothing in this code that does anything related to ASCII characters. The code simply prints out numbers, represented as the **numeric** type chart. It's up to your terminal to decide how to display those numeric values. ASCII is by far the most common code, so that's almost certainly what the terminal is treating those values as. But, again, there is nothing in the program that does anything related to ASCII.

Answer (score 6):

This condition

```
while (alphabet < 130)
```

always evaluates to true, because the `char` type typically has a range from [-128, 127]. When `alphabet` has the value 127 and is incremented by 1, it will wrap around and have the value -128. Therefore, your program tries to - somehow - print all these values. The positive ones correspond to ASCII values, where the value 7 instructs the terminal to beep.

Comment: Thank You for this solution.So This means my terminals is beeping because this loop is making it beep and going on forever

Comment: @Chinmaya That is correct. `alphabet` will cycle forever between -128 and 127, and every time its value is 7 it instructs the terminal to beep.

Comment: Just one does beep. you can try it in console :
`echo -ne '\007'`